# AngularJS Custom Validation when model is pristine

Tags: angularjs, validation

How can I make the validation set form.$valid to false when the initial value is not valid (model is pristine). If I manually change the input, the form.$valid is corrected based on the input.

http://plnkr.co/edit/lDrsCFez8PkROuEC6wvC?p=preview
(This is based on the integer directive from the Custom Validation section in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive you only specify a `$parser`.
A `$parser` takes effect when the `$viewValue` is changed, i.e. through interaction with the view (or programmatically setting the `$viewValue`).

But you are not touching the `$viewValue`, only the `$modelValue`.
If you want to perform validation when the `$modelValue` changes, you need to specify a `$formatter` as well.

---

E.g. add the following code in your linking function:

```
ctrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
    if (modelValue && !INTEGER_REGEXP.test(modelValue)) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('integer', false);
    } else {
        ctrl.$setValidity('integer', true);
    }
    // Return the original value regardless of its validity,
    // so it shows up in the view (even if it is invalid).
    return modelValue;
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mV0JJhvklke6WyuiqFV7?p=preview)**.

---

**UPDATED:**

I updated the code above and the demo to take into account the case of empty values and also properly re-validate when the `$modelValue` is changed programmatically.

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for taking the time to explain as well!

Comment: Could you explain why I need (or should) not call $setValidity with true if the regexp.test is valid?

Comment: @jostyposty: I can't explain that :) Your question made me realize that you should and you should also take into account empty values (usually validation should not be applied on empty values). Take a look at my updated demo (and answer).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use type="number"

```
<input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size" />
```

Comment: I don't like the way some browsers creates stuff inside the input when using number. Like up and down arrows. Also, in a float directive I'm creating, I need the user to be able to write 1,2 which is not a valid number. I guess I like to keep things consistent.